# Writing Custom SSL Context for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate

I finally setup the SSL in Tomcat with its default context implementation. Now, if someone knows please tell me how to write a custom SSLContext for Tomcat. Can i use the Bean for creating SSLServer Sockets and mounting them to Tomcat?..
I want to send and receive Objects through these sockets. Can I assign Tomcat to take control over these sockets?
Can I provide custom random,truststore and Keymanagers for SSL initialization?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support.  Specifically, `trustManagerClassName` (at least for handling client certificates).

Comment: +1, only available from 6.0.33 according to this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48208

Answer (score 1):

You could look for sample `SSLImplementation`s and adapt them to your needs from this page: http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/ApacheTomcatUsage